# Notifications using Long Polling in node.js mysql and socket io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, long-polling

I ma trying to make a notification system for my site using node.js mysql and socket.io
I want to have a counter of incomming messages for logged user on the page.

I have simply realised it using this query:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM messages WHERE user_get='$MY_ID'");
        $row = $result->fetch_row();
        $totalm = $row[0]; // всего записей
    $result->close();
```

and the output:

```
<div class="count"><?=$totalm;?></div>
```

But this is the static variant and it updates only if user updates the page.

I want to make a real-time notification so i moved to node.js and socket.io

Now i have my server:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var http = require('http');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
host     : 'localhost',
user     : 'root',
password : '',
database : 'lc'
});

var io = require('socket.io').listen(9000); 

io.set('log level', 3);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.on('addid', function(my_id){

        var sql    = 'SELECT COUNT(*) AS namesCount FROM messages WHERE user_get ' + connection.escape(my_id) + ' ';

    connection.query(sql, function(err, rows) {
        if(rows.length > 0) {


            socket.user = my_id;
            socket.count = rows[0].namesCount;

            console.log(socket.count+' has been logined ');

        } 
    });

        socket.on( 'notif', function(notif) {
        // htmlencode
        notif = escapeHtml(notif); 

        // Unixtime
        milliseconds = parseInt(new Date().getTime()/1000);
        var post  = {user_get: socket.user};
        query = connection.query('SELECT COUNT(*) AS namesCount FROM messages WHERE ?', post, function(err, result) {
        update = connection.query(sql);
        });


        console.log(' usersend id:  ' +socket.user +' ');
         socket.broadcast.to(socket.user).json.emit('incNotif',{'userSend': socket.user, 'notif': socket.count})
        });

    });
});
```

And the client:

```
$(window).load(function() {
var milliseconds = parseInt(new Date().getTime()/1000);
if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') != -1) {
    socket = io.connect('http://localhost:9000', {'transports': ['xhr-polling']});
} else {
    socket = io.connect('http://localhost:9000',);
}

socket.on('connect', function () {

    socket.emit('addid', '<?=$MY_ID;?>'');

    socket.on('incNotif', function (notif) {

        if(msg.userSend == id) {

                $("#mess").append(
                "<div class='count'>"+ notif +"</div>"
                );
                event.preventDefault();
        }

    });

 });

});
```

Nothing works.

I dont have enought knoledge in these technologies, so i hope you will help me.

Comment: php code works in java, i used the same construction socket.emit('addid', '<?=$MY_ID;?>''); in my private messaging system

Answer (score 0):

```
socket = io.connect('http://localhost:9000',); // empty parameter.
socket.emit('addid', '<?=$MY_ID;?>'');  // extra '.
```

In your server code

```
socket.on( 'notif', function(notif) {
```

'notif' event is not emitted from client and so 'incNotif' wont get broadcasted.

Broadcast 'incNotif' after reading from mysql.

Comment: Can you explain it in more detail please

Comment: You are not emitting a 'notif' event from your client. so socket.on('notif') block in your server wont get called. You have written your broadcast inside this block, so it wont emit 'incNotif' at all.

Comment: If you move "socket.broadcast.to(socket.user).json.emit('incNotif',{'userSend': socket.user, 'notif': socket.count})" just after you reading from mysql. it will emit 'incNotif'. Then it will come inside "socket.on('incNotif')" in client. Use a debugger(either firebug or chrome developer tools) to debug this. You can also debug  node.js server code. eg: https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector

Comment: I moved this "socket.broadcast.to(socket.user).json.emit('incNotif',{'userSend': socket.user, 'notif': socket.count})" out of "socket.on('incNotif')" to "socket.on('addid', function(my_id){", but nothing happens. It still not work